# Fill a two dimensional array passed into a function

Tags: c++, c

I try to fill a two dimensional array which I pass to a function but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
#define ROW    3
#define COLUMN 3
#define EMPTYFIELD ' '

void fillField( char** data, int row, int column );

int main( void )
{
    // Two dimensional array
    char field[ROW][COLUMN];
    fillField( field, ROW, COLUMN );
    return( 0 );
}

void fillField( char** data, int row, int column )
{
    for( int r = 0; r < row; r++ )
    {
        for( int c = 0; c < column; c++ )
        {
            *data = EMPTYFIELD;
            data++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:32: error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[3]’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void fillField(char**, int, int)’
  fillField( field, ROW, COLUMN );
                                ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void fillField(char**, int, int)’:
main.cpp:21:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]
    data = EMPTYFIELD;
         ^
Makefile:208: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

How can I solve this Problem? I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well actually this is C, but I compile it as C++ program, because I can initialise a variable within a for-loop.

Comment: Dynamic stack-based arrays are not available in standard C++.

Comment: Well,Why not use `-std=c99` option to compile it in `c99` mode which allows declaring variables inside `for` loops?

Answer (score 0):

```
char **data;
```

Is a double pointer not a 2D array you should be having something like

```
void fillField(char data[][3],int row,int column);
```

because the parameter `field` that is passed is a 2D array not a pointer.

Comment: As you use `COLUMN` in type, you may remove `column` parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry didn't get you the error was because of passing a 2D array to a double pointer so I mentioned that in my answer are you saying that the paramter `column` in the prototype is not required ?

Comment: Yeah, I tell that column parameter is superfluous.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes just kept it there to be in sync with OP's function prototype. I might very well get rid of both the paramters row and column as already they are there in the `#define` and it can be used inside the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference `data` twice.  This will solve your problem:

```
for( int r = 0; r < row; r++ )
{
    for( int c = 0; c < column; c++ )
    {
        data[r][c] = EMPTYFIELD;
    }
}
```

However, as other answers say, it's a bad idea to pass a 2-d array using `**`.